# Why my css code doesn't center the elements on the page?

Tags: html, css

I would like to center the apps icons on the page, but they are attached to the left site.. Also, the footer with the text `© webservice 2015 - Terms and conditions | Privacy Policy` - I can't find a way to center it and put it around 10px above the bottom of the page, could you help me with that? The html code is:

```
<footer>
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">   
                        <ul class="footer-nav">
                            <li><a href="#todo1">
                          <img alt="and app"
                               src="img/app_android.png" />
                        </a></li>

                        <li><a href="#todo2">
                          <img alt="iOS app"
                               src="img/app_apple.png" />
                        </a></li>

                        <li><a href="#todo2">
                          <img alt="win app"
                               src="img/app_microsoft.png" />
                        </a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">   
                    <p>© webservice 2015 - <a href="#">Terms and conditions</a> | <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

and the css code is:

```
footer {
    padding: 50px 0
}
footer h1{
    color: #24374b;
    font-size: 16px;
}
footer p {
    color: #c7cacc;
    font-size: 12px;
}
footer ul {
    margin-top: 30px
}
footer li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}
footer a {
    color: #08c;
}
footer a:hover{
    color: #c7cacc;
}
footer li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0
}
```

Here is jsfiddle for that --> http://jsfiddle.net/6q99awdf/

Thanks!

Comment: What element do you want to center? `.container`, `.row`, `.footer-nav`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `text-align: center;` to the parent. So take it from the `<li>` to the `<ul>`:

```
footer ul {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
footer li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLambha8/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    ul, p{
    text-align:center;
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siamakferdos/6q99awdf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your text-align: center; isn't applied to the text you want to center.

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxxpz8xb/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can add **.text-center** bootstrap class to your row. so it becomes to

> **class="row text-center"**

Next you need to add **"text-align: center"** for "p" tag in your css.

Position of footer at bottom depends on content in body. if you mention position as relative it will be at next to your body content.

if you have less content in body but still if it needs to fix at bottom position then below css to **footer** element.

> **position:absolute; 
>
>     bottom:10px;
>
>     padding:0px;**

**one more suggestion**

in your html code you used copy right symbol © directly. This may cause some browser compatible issues. To avoid those you can use © to render the same symbol.